# How to repeat a checkbox directive with the same model name?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I'm using a custom checkbox directive in a table I'm working on, and I'm having a problem with the model being repeated in each new row that is created.

For example, I have five checkboxes in each row - delete, id, name, access, security. When the checkbox directive is initiated, it gets passed the model name "delete" and so on, and this all works great within the first row of the table.

Once I interact with the second row, clicking on those checkboxes updates the checkbox state of the boxes in row 1.

Is there a way to provide a new scope on each instance of the checkbox where model names can be re-used, of perhaps a new scope on the row? Or would each row have to have it's own form element to isolate the models within?

Simpel HTML:

```
<checkbox model="deleteUser" checked-class="selected"></checkbox>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('att.directives').directive('checkbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: function(elem, attrs) {
            return '<div class="checkbox" ng-class="{\''+attrs.checkedClass+'\': '+attrs.model+'}">' +
                   '<input id="'+attrs.model+'" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="'+attrs.model+'">' +
                   '<label for="'+attrs.model+'"></label>' +
                   '</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you looping through some array to produce these rows?

Comment: @JamesKleeh that part's a little weird. I'm using DataTables to construct the table bases off of an array of objects. I do have a directive setup that provides a new scope to every row that's created, but that doesn't seem to do anything for the shared model names.